# How to host, write to, and push a text file to a git repo

Tags: python, google-app-engine, heroku, git-remote, gitpython

I have a very specific problem that I've absolutely no experience in and would like some guidance.

I have a simple HTML/JS form hosted on my site that asks for a phone number, and upon submit, makes a request with the number to a Python app I've hosted with Google App Engine, which then operates an API to send the text to that number.

So far, that's worked well. But I want to be able to store that number to a simple text file, and push that to my git repo, because I have a Heroku app that listens for every push to redeploy the app and run a scheduled task to send out a regular text message to every number on that now-updated list.

The problem I've run into is figuring out where this number text file is hosted and how to write to it, and then push using a library like gitpython.

It all works locally, but not when the app is built and deployed by Google App Engine/Heroku.

Comment: If you want help, you should explain what the problem you're having is when running it on Google App Engine+Heroku. That said, storing user data in a git repo sounds like a bad idea. You should use Google App Engine or Heroku's persistent storage options.

Comment: Thanks, @nog642! I did not know about their persistent storage options. I'll look that up.

Comment: Heroku, at least, doesn't _have_ persistent storage options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I want to be able to store that number to a simple text file, and push that to my git repo, because I have a Heroku app that listens for every push to redeploy the app and run a scheduled task to send out a regular text message to every number on that now-updated list.

I'm sure this isn't what you want to hear, but hard-coding data in text files and redeploying your application every time the data changes doesn't make a lot of sense. Data and code are fundamentally different things; changing data should never require an application redeploy.

Also, it's not clear *where* you're writing that file, but if it's on your Heroku server you're going to have other issues. Its filesystem is [both ephemeral and dyno-local](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem), e.g. so if you try to view a saved file via `heroku run bash` you won't see it (that runs on a [one-off dyno](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos), not a running web dyno) and it will be lost within 24 hours due to [automatic dyno restarts](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#restarting).

Saving your data in a proper client-server database instead of a text file solves both problems.

(I'm not familiar with Google App Engine, but it may have similar restrictions. Even if it doesn't, this is still a better architecture.)

Comment: Thanks, Chris! It's definitely insightful to learn about the ephemeral/dyno-local filesystem. I suspected as much, as my code would work locally but not while hosted on the web, and it's good to get a definite answer as to why.

What are your recommendations for hosting this kind of file online, then? I have in mind Django, but wasn't sure if that's over-kill for something as simple as a text file.

Comment: You don't need Django, just a database. [Heroku has a PostgreSQL service](https://www.heroku.com/postgres) with a free tier that should do more than you need, or pick [another data persistence addon](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/#data-stores). Or, if you really want to keep using a file, store it on something like Amazon S3 or Azure Blob Storage.

Comment: Thanks! I gave the PostgreSQL Heroku add-on a try, and other than brief issues with connecting to the db, it works great. Yay!